# How to merge all PART files in electron js using Node fs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I'm having list of part files in one of my local directory

```
Directory: 'C:/Users/Documents/rast'

folder: rast
|
|____ rast_001.part (approx size: 500 MB)
|
|____ rast_002.part (approx size: 500 MB)
|
|____ rast_003.part (approx size: 500 MB)
|
|____ rast_004.part (approx size: 500 MB)
|
|____ rast_005.part (approx size: 500 MB)
|
|____ rast_006.part (approx size: 500 MB)
```

I would like to merge all the part files into a single part file.

I tried the following approach but I can't able to achieve this.

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;

//requiring path and fs modules
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const outputPath = path.join('C:/Users/Documents/rast', 'output.part');


var w = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath, {flags: 'a'});

//joining path of directory 
const directoryPath = path.join('C:/Users/Documents', 'rast');

//passsing directoryPath and callback function
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {

    files.forEach(function (file) {
        const filePath = path.join('C:/Users/Documents/rast', file);
        var r = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        r.pipe(w, { end: true });
    }
});
```

If I execute this code, it creates a empty output file (Zero in size). Kindly assist me how to do this.

> Note: Part file may have any content, it may be a text file, JAR file,
>   EXE file, ZIP file, PDF, etc.,

Comment: where is the `w` defined?

Comment: @WilliamChong - Its a typo mistake. Now check the code once again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create writestream for each readstream inside pipe. Like below example. Hope this will help you. Try listening for error in write stream.

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;
var fs=require('fs');
var path=require('path');
fs.readdir('./',(err,files)=>{
  files.forEach((file)=>{
    if(file!='node_modules'){
        console.log('Appending file-->'+file);
        var stream= fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname,file))
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output.part',{flags:'a',autoClose:true})
        .on('finish',()=>{console.log('Wstrm Closed...');})
        .on('error',(err)=>{console.log('Error at writrStream-->',err)}));

        stream.on('error',(err)=>{
            console.log('Read Stream Error-->',err);
        })
        .on('close',()=>{console.log('Rdstrm closed for file-->',file)});
    }

   });
});
```